# How to integrate a numpy array in scipy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have a relatively expensive-to-calculate function which, given a single scalar, returns a numpy.array() object. When I try to integrate this function with respect to the scalar argument, using `scipy.integrate.romberg`, I get an error internal to scipy from the condition it uses to determine convergence:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wqc.py", line 148, in <module>
    H_cycle = (m.pi / wt) * scipy.integrate.romberg(H_if, 0, m.pi / wt)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py", line 471, in romberg
    while (abs(result - lastresult) > tol) and (i <= divmax):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Is there any way to integrate the entire array at once, or do I need to integrate element-by-element? I would like to avoid the second solution, as there is no easy way to calculate *just* one element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be here:

```
abs(result - lastresult) > tol
```

`result` and `lastresult` are likely numpy.arrays (instead of single values).  The above entire expression is therefore evaluating to an *array* of truth values, rather than a single `True`/`False`.  Therefore when you `and` the result of the above expression with `(i <= divmax)`, you get the error `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.`.  The suggestion by the ValueError is appropriate.  You should turn the array of truth values into a single truth value.

```
example = numpy.array([True, True, True, False])
example.any()
>>> True
example.all()
>>> False
```

This will resolve the problem.

Comment: Right, but that's occurring inside of `scipy.integrate.romberg`, not my code. I could contribute that as a patch, but if there's a more sanctioned way of integrating arrays, I'd like to do that.

Comment: Not yet, but I can make a toy program that hits upon the same error. Will get to that soon.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is ambiguous in purely mathematical sense. The integration routine has no way of knowing whether you want to integrate several scalar functions at the same time (which as far as I understand you're after), or if you're doing something like one of these beasts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus#Theorems

What I would do to here I would tabulate the expensive function, interpolate it (using scipy.interp1d or UnivariateSpline), and integrate these.

Comment: All of the theorems you linked to there regard functions of multiple variables (or alternately, or vector variables), which is why I emphasized that the function in question takes a single scalar. That said, the idea of interpolating makes a lot of sense. Do you think that memoizing the expensive function might also help?

Comment: Concerning integrals: Doing, say, a line integral involves parametrizing a line -- and what's left is an integral over a scalar variable.

Comment: Concerning memorizing: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by it. The exact technique of dealing with an expensive function of course depends on your needs. The simplest way, especially if memory is not too big of an issue, would be to just tabulate it over some grid, and deal with interpolated one only from that point on.

Answer (score -2):

http://www.sagemath.org may provide alternative ways of numerical integration.